# Refresh Datatable in for:each loop: Lightning Web Components

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am having trouble refreshing a Datatable in my Lightning Web Component after updating a record. I am calling an `onclick` action on a button within the row, and imperatively calling an Apex method to update that record. I then call the refreshApex() to update the data being fed into the Datatable.

However, after the `refreshApex()`, the tables within the for:each are not being refreshed with new data.

The records are properly modified and reflect the changes properly when refreshing the entire page.

**Note:** The Task object is not supported in LWC, and I cannot use the `updateRecord()` method to update these records.

HTML:

```html
<template>
  <template if:true="{taskCompWrapperList}">
    <!--<lightning-layout multiple-rows="false" pull-to-boundary="small">-->
    <template for:each="{taskCompWrapperList}" for:item="taskTemplate">
      <lightning-layout-item
        key="{taskTemplate.taskSectionOrder}"
        size="3"
        class="slds-p-around_x-small"
      >
        <!-- Start bear tile -->
        <lightning-card title="{taskTemplate.taskSectionTitle}">
          <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true="{taskTemplate.taskList}">
              <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data="{taskTemplate.taskList}"
                onrowaction="{handleRowAction}"
                columns="{columns}"
                onsave="{handleSave}"
                draft-values="{draftValues}"
              >
              </lightning-datatable>
            </template>
            <template if:true="{contact.error}">
              <!-- handle Apex error -->
            </template>
          </div>
        </lightning-card>
        <!-- End bear tile -->
      </lightning-layout-item>
    </template>
    <!--</lightning-layout>-->
  </template>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire ,track} from 'lwc';
import getTaskCompWrappers from '@salesforce/apex/ENT_Task_Utility.getTaskComponentWrapper';
import updateTask from '@salesforce/apex/ENT_Task_Utility.updateTask';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

const COLS = [
    {        
        type: 'button',
        label: 'Complete',
        typeAttributes: 
        {
            //iconName: 'action:preview',
            label: 'Complete',
            name: 'Complete',
            title: 'Complete',
            value: 'Complete',
            variant: 'brand',
            alternativeText: 'Complete'
        }
    },
    {        
        type: 'button-icon', 
        label: 'Start',       
        typeAttributes: 
        {
            iconName: 'action:approval',
            //label: 'Complete',
            name: 'Start',
            title: 'Start',
            value: 'Start',
            variant: 'success',            
            alternativeText: 'Start',
        }
    },
    {
        type: "button", 
        typeAttributes: 
        {  
            label: 'View',  
            name: 'View',  
            title: 'View',  
            disabled: false,  
            value: 'view',  
            iconPosition: 'left'  
        }
    },  
    {
        type: "button", 
        typeAttributes: 
        {  
            label: 'Edit',  
            name: 'Edit',  
            title: 'Edit',  
            disabled: false,  
            value: 'edit',  
            iconPosition: 'left'  
        }
    },  
    //{ label: 'Complete', fieldName: 'Task_Complete__c', editable: true },
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status', type: 'picklist', editable: true },
    { label: 'Completed', fieldName: 'Completed', type: 'boolean', editable: true },
    { label: 'Owner', fieldName: 'OwnerId', editable: true },
    { label: 'Subject', fieldName: 'Subject' },
    { label: 'Due Date', fieldName: 'ActivityDate', type: 'date' }
];

export default class ENT_Task_Utility_LWC extends LightningElement {
    @api objApiName;
    @api recordId;
    @track testMessage = 'Test Failed :c';  

    @track error;
    @track columns = COLS;
    @track draftValues = [];
    taskCompWrapperList;
    @track error;

    //@wire(getTasks, {recordId: '$recordId'}) taskList;`
    @wire(getTaskCompWrappers, {recordId: '$recordId', objApiName: '$objApiName'}) 
    taskCompWrapperListWire({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.taskCompWrapperList = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.taskCompWrapperList = undefined;
        }
    }

    updateTaskValues (taskId, taskStatus) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('updateTaskValues hit');
        for(var counter = 0; counter < this.taskCompWrapperList.length; counter++) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log('taskWrapper: ' + this.taskCompWrapperList[counter]);
            for(var counter2 = 0; counter2 < this.taskCompWrapperList[counter].taskList.length; counter2++) {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.log('task: ' + this.taskCompWrapperList[counter].taskList[counter2]);
                if(this.taskCompWrapperList[counter].taskList[counter2].Id == taskId)
                {
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Task Id Found!',
                            message: this.taskCompWrapperList[counter].taskList[counter2].Id,
                            variant: 'success'
                        })
                    );
                    this.taskCompWrapperList[counter].taskList[counter2].Status = taskStatus;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    handleRowAction(event) {
        //TODO
    }    
}
```

Apex methods:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    global static List<Task> getTasks(String recordId)
    {
        return [SELECT Id, Subject, OwnerId FROM Task WHERE WhatId = :recordId];
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    global static List<ENT_Task_Comp_Wrapper> getTaskComponentWrapper(String recordId, String objApiName)
    {
        List<Task_Template__c> taskTemplateList = [SELECT Id, Task_Component_Section_Order__c, Task_Component_Section_Title__c, (SELECT Id FROM Task_Template_Items__r) 
                                                   FROM Task_Template__c 
                                                   WHERE Active__c = true AND sObject__c = :objApiName ORDER BY Task_Component_Section_Order__c ASC];

        List<Task> taskList = [SELECT Id, Task_Template_Item__c, OwnerId, Owner.Name, Subject, Description, Status, ActivityDate, Task_Complete__c FROM TasK WHERE WhatId = :recordId];

        List<ENT_Task_Comp_Wrapper> taskCompWrapperList = new List<ENT_Task_Comp_Wrapper>();

        for(Task_Template__c taskTemplate : taskTemplateList)
        {
            ENT_Task_Comp_Wrapper taskCompWrapper = new ENT_Task_Comp_Wrapper();
            taskCompWrapper.taskSectionTitle = taskTemplate.Task_Component_Section_Title__c;
            taskCompWrapper.taskSectionOrder = (Integer)taskTemplate.Task_Component_Section_Order__c;
            taskCompWrapper.taskList = new List<Task>();

            for(Task currentTask : taskList)
            {
                for(Task_Template_Item__c taskTemplateItem : taskTemplate.Task_Template_Items__r)
                {
                    if(taskTemplateItem.Id == currentTask.Task_Template_Item__c)
                    {
                        taskCompWrapper.taskList.add(currentTask);
                    }
                }
            }

            taskCompWrapperList.add(taskCompWrapper);

        }
        System.debug(taskCompWrapperList);
        return taskCompWrapperList;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    global static void updateTask(String taskId, String newStatus)
    {
        System.debug(taskId);
        Task taskToUpdate = new Task(Id = taskId, Status = newStatus);
        update taskToUpdate;
        //update taskToUpdate;
    }

@AuraEnabled
    global static void updateTask(String taskId, String newStatus)
    {
        System.debug(taskId);
        Task taskToUpdate = new Task(Id = taskId, Status = newStatus);
        update taskToUpdate;
        //update taskToUpdate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JS code you have imported  `refreshApex` 
by using this line `import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';`

but you didn't assigned to any wire method. Hence data is not refreshed

Please refer this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex).

To refresh a wired method, pass the argument the wired method receives (which is the wired value) to `refreshApex()`. In this sample code, the wired method is `taskCompWrapperListWire`. Hold on to the value provisioned by the wire service and pass it to refreshApex().

```
@wire(getTaskCompWrappers, {recordId: '$recordId', objApiName: '$objApiName'}) 
taskCompWrapperListWire({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.taskCompWrapperList = data;
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.taskCompWrapperList = undefined;
    }
}
```

And then use `refreshApex()` as below:

```
refreshApex(this.taskCompWrapperListWire);
```

Update you code as below

```
updateTaskValues({
        taskId: this.taskId,
        taskStatus: this. taskStatus
   })
    .then(() => {
        // your code logic 
        refreshApex(this.taskCompWrapperListWire);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.message = 'Error received: code' + error.errorCode + ', ' +
            'message ' + error.body.message;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to wait for next release to have a correct way to handle such situation.

You are getting record through uiRecordApi and updating through Apex if I'm correct.
Then you would need to use `getRecordNotifyChange()` available in [Winter 21 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_lwc_modules.htm?edition=&impact=).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer provided by Sudarshan, you should also define taskCompWrapperList as a reactive property to make it rerender when the property is updated.

```
@track taskCompWrapperList = [];
```